# XPath innerText ignoring subchilds

Tags: text, xpath, parent, innertext

I want to access an element using text() attribut of xpath having a structure like shown below.

```
<root>
    <child>
        <lowerchild>
            <lowestchild>
                My text
            </lowestchild>
        </lowerchild>
    </child>
</root>
```

.

```
//child[contains(text(), 'My text')]
```

should return the child-element. and

```
//lowerchild[contains(text(), 'My text')]
```

should return the lowerchildelement.

I tried out the XPath-commands with HTMLAgilityPack, but they were not able to find those elements.

The final result of my little project is a small xpath-searcher, so the user gives the name of element the attribut and the value, so it would be great if you might give me a solution only using that information. It could be any random structure. if element names double themselves like if we had 2 lowestchild-elements, than i would like to pick the "lower" one of the lowest. Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
//child[contains(text(), 'My text')]
```

it looks like you want

```
//child[contains(., 'My text')]
```

The XPath expression `text()` (with the implicit `child::` axis) selects any text node that is a child of the context node. In the above example, it selects only text nodes that are immediate children of the `child` element. In the XML you showed, the `child` element has two child text nodes, with the `lowerchild` element in between them. Both text nodes contain only whitespace, and for this reason they may be stripped by some processors, depending on settings.

If you pass a node-set or a sequence as the first parameter to `contains(a, b)`, it takes the first node and converts it to a string. So your parameter is getting converted to a string containing only whitespace, or else an empty string (if the whitespace-only text nodes got stripped).

But if instead of `text()` you pass `.` as the first argument to `contains()`, then the context node (which is a `child`) gets converted to a string. This means concatenating the values of all text node **descendants** of `child`, not just immediate text node **children**. (It's sort of like DOM `innerText`, which your question title mentions, but does not include start/end tags of elements, nor attributes.) For this reason, `//child[contains(., 'My text')]` will return the `child` element.

Comment: sorry, i was translating the text into english and thus i didnt see your answer.

Comment: @OP: No problem... I removed the mention of German from my answer. I don't really understand the last paragraph of your question though. Can you give complete examples of what you mean about picking the "lower" one of the lowest?

Comment: @Iwan1993: Did this answer help? If not, could you explain in more detail what you need? (See previous comment.)

Comment: Well, with "lower" lowerestchild-element i meant the lowest child element, or the next parent element with the fitting name. But thank you for the answer, good explanation and personal thumbs up. :)